# Chess tournament [contest math]

Tags: graph-theory, contest-math

There are 15 players in chess tournament. And each player should play with all other players. Is it possible that each player will have exactly 5 games ended by draw?

I am trying to get contradiction but no results. On the one hand, there are total $105$ games.

How to get contradiction?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

$15\times 5$ should count each such game twice. But what about that number?

Comment: Half of that. But it is not an integer.

Comment: @RFZ exactly and non-integer number of games can not be played.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

- How many of the $105$ games would then be drawn?

Comment: I guess $5 \times 15$?

Comment: And if each player drew $14$ times, would that mean there would be $14\times 15=210$ draws out of $105$ games?